# JDeveloper - WAR WebLogic Server to Deploy TomCat

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, war, jdeveloper

I am developing an application with JDeveloper IDE and WebLogic Server.
I'm having problems to deploy the WAR in Tomcat generated by WebLogic

some configuration to be done in web.xml?
Some LIB to be added?

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Please provide more details on the problems you are having.

Comment: Exception starting filter adfBindings
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter

Comment: tomcat generates this exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADF Essentials on Tomcat - see setup instructions here:
http://technology.amis.nl/2014/01/03/deploy-oracle-adf-essentials-web-application-on-tomcat/

You can't use the full ADF on Tomcat though.